# inverse fourier transform in R

Tags: python, r

this is python script

```
  np.fft.ifft([0, 4, 0, 0])
 # OUTPUT ([ 1.+0.j,  0.+1.j, -1.+0.j,  0.-1.j]) 
 #I WANT THIS IN R
```

if I pass this in R

```
  fft(c(0, 4, 0, 0),inverse=TRUE)
  output
  4+0i  0+4i -4+0i  0-4i
```

how can i do this , suggest me

Comment: You need to divide by the length of the input signal when doing inverse fft in R: `fft(x),inverse=TRUE)/length(x)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
a<- c(0, 4, 0, 0)

fft(a),inverse=TRUE)/length(a)

#output 1+0i  0+1i -1+0i  0-1i
```